# Missing value in a range because no one chose option 5 so it breaks my for loop at index 5

Tags: python, pandas

How do I make python interpret the gap and fill it in with a 5 index and 0 value?

I'm creating a function to automatically calculate survey responses for ANOVA testing, and bar chart crafting simultaneously.

I came across the problem of none of all respondents older than 65 did not mark option 5 so it's blank. This breaks the for loop I'm using because it goes by range(7).

How do I write a code beforehand or into the line that even if it no one chose 5, then it can include it automatically and assign a 0 value.

```
a1y=[]
b2y=[]
c3y=[]
d4y=[]
e5y=[]
for item in range(7):
    
    ar = grp1['Q22'].value_counts()
    br = grp2['Q22'].value_counts()
    cr = grp3['Q22'].value_counts()
    dr = grp4['Q22'].value_counts()
    er = grp5['Q22'].value_counts()
 
    a1y.append(ar[item+1])
    b2y.append(br[item+1])
    c3y.append(cr[item+1])
    d4y.append(dr[item+1])
    e5y.append(er[item+1])

grp5['Q22'].value_counts()

 7.0    16
 4.0    14
 6.0    11
 2.0     8
 3.0     2
-1.0     2
 1.0     1
Name: Q22, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a simple try and except statement on any option so if it errors you can handle that. To do this just add a try statement above the code you want to handle and an except statement with what should happen if it errors.

Like so:

```
try:                                                                                                 
  # CODE THAT MIGHT ERROR                                                                            
  er = grp5['Q22'].value_counts()                                                                     
except:                                                                                              
  # CODE THAT SHOULD BE EXECUTED IF THE ABOVE CODE ERRORS                                            
  er = 0
```

You can make this more specific so that the code after the except statement is only executed when a specific error happens. This is preferred because then if your program crashes on that line for another/unexpected reason you can know that its breaking.

Do this by adding the error name after the except statement:

```
except ERRORNAME:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your results `a1y`, `b2y`, `c3y` etc. should be a `dict`Object , not a `list` Object , I think.

```
# all the needed keys you modified
keys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  
# get the difference set 
diff = set(keys).difference(set(grp5['Q22'].value_counts().index))
# get result 
e5y = grp5['Q22'].value_counts().to_dict()
# add the index with 0 value
for none_value_key in diff:
    e5y = {**e5y, **{none_value_key:  0}}
```